# CentOS 7 pgbouncer.pid Permissions Issue

Tags: postgresql, centos7, pgbouncer

I have installed pgbouncer.  I can't get it started because the directory that houses the `.pid` file re-generates its own ownership.

```
2020-07-31 04:58:34.083 EDT [3682] DEBUG loading auth_file: "/etc/pgbouncer/userlist.txt"
2020-07-31 04:58:34.088 EDT [3682] DEBUG pktbuf_dynamic(128): 0x8d52f0
2020-07-31 04:58:34.088 EDT [3682] DEBUG make_room(0x8d52f0, 9): realloc newlen=256
2020-07-31 04:58:34.088 EDT [3682] DEBUG pktbuf_dynamic(128): 0x8d54d0
2020-07-31 04:58:34.089 EDT [3682] FATAL could not open pidfile '/var/run/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.pid': Permission denied
```

I've set the permissions on `/var/run/pgbouncer/` to `postgres:postgres` after the original installation (forget what those permissions were) and it is still being denied due to permissions. I restart the box and the permissions change back to `pgbouncer:pgbouncer`.  So it seems the package install forms this permissions issue right from the start.

How can I get `pgbouncer` to work?  Any insight appreciated.  Cheers